# When to use snd_pcm_avail instead of snd_pcm_avail_update?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

ALSA functions `snd_pcm_avail` and `snd_pcm_avail_update` are very similar. Most examples seem to use `snd_pcm_avail_update`. When should I use `snd_pcm_avail` instead?

In my test program it does not seem to make a difference which function I use. What is the difference?

Comment: What about the [documentation](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga577b4d51e08d94930a05bbe73291ed2a)?

Comment: Well, I read the documentation, but it is still not clear to me when to use which function. Maybe I lack some background to understand the information provided but I find it very brief. Sorry, if it is obvious.

Comment: [test/pcm.c](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2pcm_8c-example.html) uses only snd_pcm_avail_update no matter whether it uses poll()/select()  or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`snd_pcm_avail_update()` does not go to the kernel to read the latest status, so the information might be out of date. This is just an optimization that is useful when used directly after a call that already has updated the status, such as `poll()` or `snd_pcm_status()`.